# Oracle database schema export

Tags: oracle-linux, data-pump

I'm trying to run a schema export through `expdep` on an oracle database:

```
expdp somedatabase/something directory=EXP_DIR schemas=someschema dumpfile=dumpfile.dmp logfile=logfile.log
```

The above command (although edited for the purpose of posting this question) has been working before, but now I get this error:

```
ORA-31626: job does not exist
ORA-31633: unable to create master table "SOMEDATABASE.SYS_EXPORT_SCHEMA_09"
ORA-06512: at "SYS.DBMS_SYS_ERROR", line 95
ORA-06512: at "SYS.KUPV$FT", line 1161
ORA-01658: unable to create INITIAL extent for segment in tablespace USERS
ORA-06512: at "SYS.KUPV$FT", line 1054
ORA-06512: at "SYS.KUPV$FT", line 1042
```

I have reason to believe that the root cause is that there are stalled jobs relating to earlier data pumps that were semi-aborted (ctrl+c) with their destination files removed.

How do I go about clearing these jobs so that I can restart the data pump from scratch?

From the looks of it, I am running version 12.2.0.1 on Centos.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to find a sollution buried deep inside google search results. This worked for me:

**Step 1: Find stalled jobs:**

```
SELECT o.status, o.object_id, o.object_type,        o.owner||'.'||object_name "OWNER.OBJECT"      FROM dba_objects o, dba_datapump_jobs j      WHERE o.owner=j.owner_name AND o.object_name=j.job_name       AND j.job_name NOT LIKE 'BIN$%' ORDER BY 4,2;
```

**Step 2, Remove them:**

```
drop table TABLENAME_RETURNED_IN_STEP_1;
```

After this I was able to do the export as before.