# Oracle database export error

Tags: oracle-linux

I am trying to export oracle database but I get error. the error is similar to this question [Oracle database schema export](https://serverfault.com/questions/1003429/oracle-database-schema-export),  but if I run the the query `SELECT o.status, o.object_id, o.object_type, o.owner||'.'||object_name "OWNER.OBJECT" FROM dba_objects o, dba_datapump_jobs j WHERE o.owner=j.owner_name AND o.object_name=j.job_name AND j.job_name NOT LIKE 'BIN$%' ORDER BY 4,2;` i will get `no rows selected`

```
expdp oracle/oracle123@oracle-db-1:1521/oracle dumpfile=oracle_dump_121522.dmp exclude=STATISTICS DIRECTORY=dumps compression=all logfile=oracle_dump_121522.log PARALLEL=4
```

I get error

```
Export: Release 12.2.0.1.0 - Production on Thu Dec 15 18:18:32 2022

Copyright (c) 1982, 2017, Oracle and/or its affiliates.  All rights reserved.

Connected to: Oracle Database 12c Enterprise Edition Release 12.2.0.1.0 - 64bit Production
ORA-31626: job does not exist
ORA-31633: unable to create master table "oracle.SYS_EXPORT_SCHEMA_05"
ORA-06512: at "SYS.DBMS_SYS_ERROR", line 95
ORA-06512: at "SYS.KUPV$FT", line 1161
ORA-01552: cannot use system rollback segment for non-system tablespace 'USERS'
ORA-06512: at "SYS.KUPV$FT", line 1054
ORA-06512: at "SYS.KUPV$FT", line 1042
```

Comment: Grant `create table` privilege to the user so data pump status table can be created.

Comment: And this question is more appropriate here: https://dba.stackexchange.com/